# Import "bpy" could not be resolved Pylancereport(MissingImports) in Python 3.10.2 + Blender API + VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, blender

I'm trying to develop a Blender 3D script using VS Code. But when I import bpy I get this message:

`Import "bpy" could not be resolved Pylancereport(MissingImports)`

- VSCode: 1.63.2

  - Python extension: v2021.12.1559732655
  - Blender Development extension: v0.0.16
- Python 3.10.2
- Windows 10
- Blender 3D: 3.0

I've installed fake-bpy-module-3.0.

How could I use Blender modules inside VS Code?

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://polynook.com/tutorial/set-up-blender-addon-development-environment-in-windows/